# Google Apps Script alternative to ScriptProperties

Tags: google-apps-script

Can someone suggest an alternative to ScriptProperties as a means of storing and retrieving short-term (textual) data.

I have a long-standing application built in GAS. Because it kicks off a number of 'threads' I store some information about each thread, ultimately to determine when all the threads have finished and thus when the application can release various 'locks'.

I'm using ScriptProperties to store this information. It used to work perfectly but has been beset by troubles over the last 6 months or so. The problems are mainly:
1. Application load times increase massively as more and more data collects in script properties (it isnt possible to clean down scriptproperty data)
2. ScriptProperties are (now) unreliable under concurrent access
3. ScriptProperties can't be read or written to in rapid bursts

Someone has suggested using ScriptDb. Can anyone confirm this (or any other) viable solution?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you have a look at CacheService ? I have used with lot of success.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be what I'm looking for. Essentially the difference between scriptproperties and cacheservice seem to be that the (1) private cache is scoped for a particular user (2) cache objects can be deleted (hooray!)?

Have you had any difficulties with (1) concurrently accessing a particular cache key/value pair, or (2) rate limits? Both are problems with ScriptProperties.

Comment: Not sure about concurrent access but I haven't the rate problems that comes with ScriptProperties. For concurrent access, you can use the LockService though

Answer (score 0):

CacheService is only best-effort and is not intended for guaranteed storage (but it is fast!). If you need to be sure it will be there, use ScriptDb.