# Google Apps Script: alternative to Script Properties

Tags: google-apps-script

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797773/google-apps-script-alternative-to-scriptproperties) posed a few years ago and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27165435/spreadsheet-or-script-properties-for-simple-index-in-google-apps-script), but there are no suitable answers, see below.

I want to store running indices of data and started to use script properties. I quickly ran into problems with script properties, as I was writing them in loops like so, and was hitting rate limits:

```
for (i = 0; i < fieldCountAccounts; i++) {
  scriptProperties.setProperty('fieldIndex_accounts' + accountsFields.getValues()[0][i], i+1);
}
```

This prevented functions from running, and also prevented my sidebar UI from working. So I introduced `Utilities.sleep(1000);` into the loop, which solved the problem of the functions but slowed them down hugely. Sidebar still didn't work.

Previously I was using hard-coded column numbers to address certain data, and indices stored in a sheet.

Answers to the other questions on SO:

- use CacheService (not useful as these are scoped for user)
- use ScriptDB (now deprecated)

Should I just store my key pairs in a dedicated sheet and be done with it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually looking for an answer to this as well.  I've seen some tutorials about using Google Cloud Datastore, which might be helpful here:

http://blog.warehouseman.com/2014/10/getting-started-with-google-cloud.html

It seems like part of this tutorial is outdated though, since it get's me 90% of the way there and then throws an error on the last few steps.